# When importing to Unity, armature ruins mesh smoothness

Tags: mesh, weight-painting, unity, vertex-weights, smooth

When I import a mesh by itself, it looks smooth and normal. When I import a mesh with armature(weighted) it makes the mesh look not smooth. Basically I think the weight on the armature is somehow changing the position of vertices or edges so that it does not look smooth whereas when I import only the mesh, there's no weight therefore nothing is being changed.
The left of the image is when I imported the mesh with armature and the right is when I only imported the mesh. They are both set in the same pose and nothing is different except for the armature weights. How do I fix this issue? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering if this is really a Blender issue or rather one in Unity? Since I guess in Blender everything looks fine? If not, you should show us how it looks there so that it belongs on this site for Blender problems.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.